# Strong sequential equilibria and the existence of others

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bayesian-game, signaling

I am working on the following game

[image]

and I have **to find all strong sequential equilibria here**.

I determined that here any belief derived from a fully mixed strategy gives a distribution (1/2, 1/2) over the nodes in Player 2’s information set. Given this, player 2 will chose r and player 1 will chose y. I believe that this is the unique sequential equilibrium. But is it strong?

And **are there any other Nash equilibria and if so why they are not sequential?**

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "strong" SE? Also the belief you derive for P2 in a fully mixed equilibrium seems incorrect. The resulting strategies ($y$ for P1 and $r$ for P2) are not "fully mixed", and do not induce the $(\frac12,\frac12)$ belief for P2.

Comment: @HerrK, well, strong is standart sequential equilibria, not weak.
And I don't see why they are not fully mixed

Comment: Aren't $y$ and $r$ pure strategies?

Comment: @HerrK, yes they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three classes of equilibria of this game.

---

The first class is sequential:
\begin{equation}
(s_1,s_2)=(y,r)
\end{equation}
and the beliefs are
\begin{equation}
\mu_1(a)=\mu_1(b)=\mu_2(a\mid y)=\mu_2(b\mid y)=\frac12.
\end{equation}

[image]

---

The second class is not sequential, but weak perfect Bayesian:
\begin{equation}
(s_1,s_2)=(x,l)
\end{equation}
and the beliefs are
\begin{equation}
\mu_1(a)=\mu_1(b)=\frac12,\quad\text{but }\mu_2(a\mid y)=1-\mu_2(b\mid y)=p>\frac58.
\end{equation}

[image]

---

The third class is actually a boundary case of the second class, which permits P2 to use mixed strategies. This equilibrium requires P2's off equilibrium belief to be
\begin{equation}
\mu_2(a\mid y)=1-\mu_2(b\mid y)=\frac58,
\end{equation}
so that P2 can play a mixed strategy that puts sufficiently high probability on $l$ ($\sigma_2(l)\ge\frac35$). It is also necessary that P1 does not play $y$ with positive probability, because if they do, Bayes rule would kick in, requiring that P2's belief be $(\frac12,\frac12)$ instead of $(\frac58,\frac38)$ which rationalizes P2's mixed strategy.
[image]